# Objective C: UILongPressGesture on ScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying this code on UIScrollView but it's not working. The NSLog is not appearing on my console. What's wrong? its working fine when its not on UIScrollView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self papers];

    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[ UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPressGR = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
    longPressGR.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
    [Image1 addGestureRecognizer:longPressGR];
}

-(void) handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  { 

    NSLog(@"Long Press");
}
```

Comment: Is this like homework for a class or something? 2 people asking the same question lol. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937458/objective-c-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-error

Comment: haha! yeah maybe you saw my friend Ramiro. we're trying to figure it out on our own first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what Image1 is. I'm guessing a UIImageView, in which case you need to make sure you do:

```
[Image1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

(Unlike most views, UIImageView has interaction disabled by default.)

(As an aside, it's conventional in Objective-C to have your ivars and methods begin with lower-case letters; classes begin with upper-case.)